# Have multiple title bars in VLC player, is there a way to disable one of them?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, title-bar

An additional title bar appears on my VLC player which doesn't go away in full screen view. Is there a way to remove it?

[image: Additional title bar]

[image: full screen view]

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you have enabled tabs in an app that doesn't support them - the result appears as a double title bar.

Sierra comes with a feature that allows compatible applications to create multiple tabs in one window, much like a web browser. 
On an incompatible application, accessing this - using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>  will generate a second title bar below the regular one, with no apparent way to get rid of it.

Try hitting  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>  again, then relaunching the app.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to uncheck the media title display setting. For an old version of VLC (v2.0.3), the setting was located at:
**Preferences > Show All > Video > uncheck "Show media title on video"**

Source: [VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=102944)

Comment: That's the overlay when the file starts playing, looks a bit like subtitles but with either the name of the file, or if done properly, the name of the programme.